# Use YANG Tools as a Java code generator for MD-SAL in Opendaylight

Tags: generator, opendaylight, model-driven, ietf-netmod-yang

Recently I study the API definition for Opendaylight.

As we know, YANG is a modeling language for NETCONF. However, Opendaylight uses it as a Java code generator for MD-SAL.

So I am wondering :

1. How does YANG Tool help generate Java code for MD-SAL?
2. Do you have some YANG code generator tutorials?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does YANG Tool help generate Java code for MD-SAL?

YANG defines the  data definition model which is used by MD-SAL to model messages sent  by  client application.
There are two types of  API used by  client  applications. DOM and Binding Aware. Data models in both API types can be modeled by  YANG.

Binding Aware  APIs
 have a method for each leaf in the  yang model, they 
 are compiled against  the  YANG model and they 
 have concrete data structure.

DOM APIs
 used in datastore
 ,they can implement general purpose  models, runtime  adaption of model is possible and they  are not typesafe.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller%3aMD-SAL).

There are loads of tutorials there, as well as a WebEx recording etc.

Comment: It is generally preferable to avoid link only answers as the link may go dead or change radically. Try and sum up the parts of the link that answer the question and use the links as a reference.

Comment: link is not valid anymore